# ReactJS: Form onSubmit failing to call callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a chat tutorial on YouTube found here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vcIW0CO07k

Near the 3-4 minute mark, the tutorial begins to add `onChange` and `onSubmit` event handlers.

At this point, I should be able to click the button and an alert window should open with the input value.

Here is what I have for the UsernameForm.js file:

```
import React from 'react'

class UsernameForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        username: ''
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        username: e.target.value,
    })
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.username)
}

render () {
    return <div>
        <form>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="What is your username?" 
                onChange={this.onChange} 
            />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
  }
}

export default UsernameForm;
```

In the Apps.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UsernameForm from './components/UsernameForm'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <UsernameForm onSubmit={username => alert(username)} />
  }
}

export default App
```

Compiling is successful, but no alert window.  The page just refreshes.

Does anyone see why the alert window is not firing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onSubmit` callback prop that you've added needs to be invoked by the `form` element itself. You can do this by adding `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}` to the `<form />` in `UsernameForm`:

```
render () {
    return <div>
        {/* form has onSubmit callback prop which is invoked when the
        form itself is submit. Wire your components onSubmit (ie 
        this.onSubmit) to the form's callback to solve the problem */}
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}> 
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="What is your username?" 
                onChange={this.onChange} 
            />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Passing `this.onSubmit` to the form's `onSubmit` callback prop causes the `onSubmit()` method that you've defined to be called, which in turn causes the callback passed to `UsernameForm` (ie where your alert is) to be invoked.

Comment: Wow.  How did I miss that?  The guy in the tutorial talks fast.  Thank you, sir.  That fixed my problem.